# PHP variable won't assign to array value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to assign `$totalPrice` a value from the array below but it is only returning 0, the echo `$totalPrice` is in some HTML code, if I use echo $sites[$site][0] it displays the value, but not when assigning it to `$totalPrice`?

```
$totalPrice = 0;
$site = "UM";

$totalPrice = $sites[$site][0];


    $sites = array
    (
        "US" => array (38.78, 11, 5.5),
        "UM" => array (44.55, 11, 5.5),
        "PS" => array (55.28, 11, 5.5),
        "PM" => array (66.55, 11, 5.5)
    )

    echo $totalPrice;
```

Comment: I can't seem to find `$totalPeople` in your code, also in the 3rd line, you are using `$sites` before declaring it.

Comment: the (corrected) code works as expected: https://3v4l.org/SgdUu - the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Jeff how is it possible to work when `$sites` is used before being initialized?

Comment: @Mehdi true. I expected it a copy&paste mistake here, since shown code also produces a syntax error.

Comment: @Jeff yeah I deleted the comment after you added the _corrected_ part

Comment: @RJD the statements are executed in the order you write them in the file. When the line `$totalPrice = $sites[$site][0];` is executed, `$sites` does not exist yet. Accordingly, PHP issues a notice (you probably don't see) and sets `$totalPrice` to `NULL` (i.e. unset/undefined).

Comment: You're missing a `;` after your `$sites` array. Also, turn on error reporting and you will get a `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: sites in ... on line 6`

Comment: here's the code exactly as written https://3v4l.org/onBqI

Comment: May you address the questions/criticism surrounding the fact that you're trying to use `$sites` before you define it…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code..you need to declare `$totalPrice` below array value...

```
$totalPrice = 0;
$site = "UM";


    $sites = array(
        "US" => array (38.78, 11, 5.5),
        "UM" => array (44.55, 11, 5.5),
        "PS" => array (55.28, 11, 5.5),
        "PM" => array (66.55, 11, 5.5)
    );

    $totalPrice = $sites[$site][0];
echo $totalPrice;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$totalPrice = 0;
$site = "UM";

$sites = array
(
    "US" => array (38.78, 11, 5.5),
    "UM" => array (44.55, 11, 5.5),
    "PS" => array (55.28, 11, 5.5),
    "PM" => array (66.55, 11, 5.5)
);
$totalPrice = $sites[$site][0];


echo $totalPrice;
```

you used `$totalPrice = $sites[$site][0];` variable `$sites` before initialize, that's why it gives you answer 0 every time.

Comment: you have a syntax error.

Comment: And also this is not a good way to answer, add an explanation. Tell OP why his code is wrong and why yours is correct.